# Multiple text:{} content in multiple tags with Emmet

Tags: html, emmet

I want know how to write different text content every `td` in `tr`.

What I know to do is:

```
table>tr*4>td*4{my td}
```

What will happen is:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>my td</td>
  <td>my td</td>
  <td>my td</td>
  <td>my td</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>my td</td>
  <td>my td</td>
  <td>my td</td>
  <td>my td</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>my td</td>
  <td>my td</td>
  <td>my td</td>
  <td>my td</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>my td</td>
  <td>my td</td>
  <td>my td</td>
  <td>my td</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And what i want to do is:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>my td-1</td>
  <td>my td-2</td>
  <td>my td-3</td>
  <td>my td-4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>my td-5</td>
  <td>my td-6</td>
  <td>my td-7</td>
  <td>my td-8</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>my td-9</td>
  <td>my td-10</td>
  <td>my td-11</td>
  <td>my td-12</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>my td-13</td>
  <td>my td-14</td>
  <td>my td-15</td>
  <td>my td-16</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

is this doable? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
table>tr*5>td{$ my data}*4
```

[Link to Cheet Sheet for Emmet](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/)

Comment: its not going well. i get new tr tag every td tag.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can get is:

`table>tr*4>td*4>{mytd-$}`

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>mytd-1</td>
    <td>mytd-2</td>
    <td>mytd-3</td>
    <td>mytd-4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mytd-1</td>
    <td>mytd-2</td>
    <td>mytd-3</td>
    <td>mytd-4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mytd-1</td>
    <td>mytd-2</td>
    <td>mytd-3</td>
    <td>mytd-4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mytd-1</td>
    <td>mytd-2</td>
    <td>mytd-3</td>
    <td>mytd-4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

From [Emmet cheat sheet](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) > Item Numbering section

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for, sorry.